# Pagination of JSON output API

Tags: php, api, pagination

From an API, via the URL I get a JSON output which I decode into an array that contains:

```
array(3) {
  ["ProductsSummary"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Records"]=>
    int(90)
    ["TotalRecords"]=>
    int(2724)
    ["TotalPages"]=>
    int(31)
    ["CurrentPage"]=>
    int(1)
  }
```

So CurrentPage can be changed by the GET method. How could I create a Pagination?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? From what I understand your server-side PHP script fetches data from a third-party API and you want to send a paginated sub-set of that data. Is it correct that the received JSON contains lots of records that you want to split in sub-pages so the client doesn't have to view all the results at once? Could you also show what you have tried and what went wrong?

Comment: Under the mentioned array, there is data of products i already use, but i can only display 90 products, when I want to show the next 90 products I send another request and get another JSON where CurrentPage is 2 and so on. So I need a pagination which do it over the GET method. So the pagination for the mentioned array should be like http://blog.platinastudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Download-Slick-Pagination-Links-Design-PSD-for-Free.jpg but with 31 pages..

Comment: What tools are you using? Plain PHP? Some framework like Zend or Symfony? Or are you calling the 3rd party API with AJAX calls from the client-side? Are you using any templating library like Twig or Mustache?

Comment: Just PHP I call JSON like http://api/productservice.svc/JSON/SearchProducts?publisherId=bla&Password=bla&search=bla&currentpage=bla i decode the received file to array

Comment: So, [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)? If you're using plain PHP scripting you could just build the pagination dynamically, using a loop and a few conditionals based on the value of `TotalPages` and `CurrentPage`. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes but i'm beginner and need some sample code

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQgrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) which is a great jQuery plugin for handling tables and paging, it requires json in a very specific format however.

OR, you can use jQuery [Data Tables](https://datatables.net/) plug in